FFmpeg and OpenCV: Issues with RTSP Stream Decoding from H.265 Camera (SIYI A8 mini gimbal camera)
I am working on an object detection and tracking project using a camera that streams H.265 video over RTSP (rtsp://192.168.144.25:8554/main.264. However, I am encountering issues with both FFmpeg, ffplay, VLC and all other media players while decoding the stream.
All the media players are having glitch in the frame (packet loss). I am using Ubuntu 20.04 but my final deployment will be in Jetson Xavier NX. Both are having this problem. I am new to this field, Kindly give your suggestions.
Commands used are:
aadarsh@aadarsh-B560M:~/Desktop$ sudo ip link set enp3s0 up
[sudo] password for aadarsh: 
aadarsh@aadarsh-B560M:~/Desktop$ sudo ethtool enp3s0
aadarsh@aadarsh-B560M:~/Desktop$ sudo ethtool enp3s0
Settings for enp3s0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 10Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: off
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: d
    Link detected: yes
        aadarsh@aadarsh-B560M:~/Desktop$ ping 192.168.144.25
        PING 192.168.144.25 (192.168.144.25) 56(84) bytes of data.
        64 bytes from 192.168.144.25: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=5.56 ms
        64 bytes from 192.168.144.25: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=2.82 ms
        64 bytes from 192.168.144.25: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.386 ms
        64 bytes from 192.168.144.25: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.889 ms
        64 bytes from 192.168.144.25: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=1.47 ms
        64 bytes from 192.168.144.25: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.869 ms
        64 bytes from 192.168.144.25: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.770 ms
        64 bytes from 192.168.144.25: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.378 ms
        64 bytes from 192.168.144.25: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=0.408 ms


wWhat I tried:
1.Using FFmpeg to decode the stream:
Expected: Smooth playback and decoding of the H.265 RTSP stream without frame drops or errors.

Result: Frequent errors like Could not find ref with POC, RTP: missed packets, and occasional process termination due to resource exhaustion.


OpenCV for real-time processing:
Expected: Continuous frame capture with minimal latency for further processing using YOLOv8.
Result: Slow frame processing, frequent frame drops, and delayed responses.

Increasing buffer size and using hardware acceleration:
Expected: Reduced frame drops and improved decoding stability.
Result: Minor improvement, but errors and instability persist.

Testing with VLC and FFplay:
Expected: Consistent playback of the RTSP stream.
Result: VLC and FFplay show similar issues with "Waiting for VPS/SPS/PPS"



How to run packaged software is off topic here.  There is no source code to consider in this question.

"Thank you for your feedback. While I am troubleshooting the issue using terminal commands (like ffplay and ethtool), the core problem involves processing RTSP streams effectively, which is an important part of media programming. Though my current approach doesn't involve writing code, the issue is inherently tied to handling media streams, and as I continue to work on it, I might move towards using these streams for detection.
However, if you believe this is more suited to a different platform, I'd be happy to follow your suggestion on where to ask further. Thanks!"
